# NSubstitute - mock out parameter behaviour for any parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, nsubstitute

I'm trying to mock `IConfigurationProvider` with NSubstitute. I need the method `bool TryGet(string key, out string value)` to return values for differing keys. So something like this:

```
var configProvider = Substitute.For<IConfigurationProvider>();
configProvider.TryGet("key1", out Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(x => 
    { x[1] = "42"; return true; });
```

but this does not compile.
I need the mocked method to actually set the out parameter to the appropriate value, regardless of what that parameter is - it's a dependency, the unit under test calls this method with its own parameters and I just want it to "return" (as in return by filling the out parameter) correct values for keys.

This should give more perspective on the problem:

```
var value = "";
var configProvider = Substitute.For<IConfigurationProvider>();
configProvider
.TryGet("key1", out value)
.Returns(x => { 
    x[1] = "42"; 
    return true; 
});

var otherValue = "other";
configProvider.TryGet("key1", out value);
configProvider.TryGet("key1", out otherValue);

Assert.AreEqual("42", value);      // PASS.
Assert.AreEqual("42", otherValue); // FAIL.
```

I need both assertions to be true, since this method will be used by the tested class and it's free to pass any out parameter it wants, I just need to fill it with "42".

Comment: `configProvider.TryGet("key1", out Arg.Any<string>())` is not valid c# syntax

You need to use an actual variable for the *out* parameter.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`configProvider.TryGet("key1", out Arg.Any<string>())` is not valid C# syntax, which is why it wont compile.

You need to use an actual variable for the *out* parameter.

The following works when tested.

```
//Arrange            
var expectedResult = true;
var expectedOut = "42";
var actualOut = "other";
var anyStringArg = Arg.Any<string>();
var key = "key1";
var configProvider = Substitute.For<IConfigurationProvider>();
configProvider
    .TryGet(key, out anyStringArg)
    .Returns(x => {
        x[1] = expectedOut;
        return expectedResult;
    });

//Act
var actualResult = configProvider.TryGet(key, out actualOut);

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(expectedOut, actualOut); // PASS.
Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult); // PASS.
```

Answer (score 6):

As of NSubstitute 4+ this is supported out the box:

> Matching out and ref args
>
> ---
>
> Argument matchers can also be used with out and ref (NSubstitute 4.0
> and later with C# 7.0 and later).
>
> ```
> calculator
>     .LoadMemory(1, out Arg.Any<int>())
>     .Returns(x => {
>         x[1] = 42;
>         return true;
>     });
>
> var hasEntry = calculator.LoadMemory(1, out var memoryValue);
> Assert.AreEqual(true, hasEntry); Assert.AreEqual(42, memoryValue);
> ```

[Source](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/#matching-out-and-ref-args)

Make sure you note the argument index used above (`x[1] = 42;`), this array includes the **input and output** variables but you can only set the value of an `out` variable.

Comment: It seems that a later update to the compiler may have eliminated that usage option, at least in the case where the returned value is an object of some sort. I'm getting a failure to compile with a CS1510 error in Visual Studio 2019 v16.9.6.